# Extend Session Time On Button Click Event Server Side

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to extend the session of a user the moment they click a button that fires up code behind logic. Example I need to 100 people to a gridview and each time I add a person I want the session to be reset to 30 minutes.

I need to set the timeout on a certain page not the whole site. When a user makes a button click fire the timeout resets. So if the timeout on the page is 30 min, you wait 29 minutes then click the button the timeout is 30 min again.

Comment: The sesssion expiration time is reset when there is a postback. What's not working of that?

Comment: @Redi I need to set the timeout on a certain page not the whole site. When a user makes a button click fire the timeout resets. So if the timeout on the page is 30 min, you wait 29 minutes then click the button the timeout is 30 min again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens automatically. Every time the user submits a request to the server, the server extends the session. The session is "sliding".

In case you're asking how to set it to 30 minutes instead of the default (20) - there are various places to change the default, for example web.config or IIS.